# Xcode debugger crashing macOS application

Tags: xcode, macos

I've been developing a macOS application using Xcode, and it's always built and run absolutely fine. This morning, however, I've run into issues getting it to run with Xcode — it crashes at launch! The application builds fine, and if the executable is launched manually or with LLDB in terminal the application runs fine and doesn't crash. It *only* crashes when the Xcode debugger is attached. The weirdest thing is that it was absolutely fine yesterday, yet I have changed nothing.

I have tried:

1. Clearing DerivedData
2. Clearing caches
3. Rebooting
4. Reinstalling Xcode

The crash is always on Thread 5, with no apparent cause and no error message. The crash log can be found here: https://paste.mod.gg/ajiyekumot.php

Comment: Maybe it's caused by Catalina autoupdate. Does it crash if you create new MacOS application project?

Comment: Do you have any sanitizers enabled? Check by choosing "Edit Scheme..." and looking in the diagnostics tab. This resembles an issue with thread sanitizer on current Xcode versions.

Comment: @Kamil.S Yes, it does happen when I create an entirely new project.

Comment: @TheNextman No, I do not have any sanitizers enabled.